# Conditional databinding to TextField Control using filter

Tags: reactjs, filter, material-ui, textfield

My textfield is binding with a field as follows

```
          <TextField
          fullWidth
          id="phLevel"
          name="phLevel"
          label="Ph Level"
          value={form.sampleObservations.filter(filterByPhLevel)}
            onChange={updateField}
            />
```

sampleObservations is an object array and I need to bind with "value" field where field "ObservationsId" = 4

```
function filterByPhLevel(item){
  if(item.observationsId == 4)
  return item.Value;      
}
```

My json is here:

```
     {
  "sampleObservations": [
            {
                "observationsId": 4,
                "selected": true,
                "value": "testdata"
            },
            {
                "observationsId": 6,
                "selected": true,
                "value": null
            }
        ],
        "id": 459,
        "batchId": 333,
         ...
         }
```

What am I doing wrong? It says

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

form is coming from parent component so could it be that object to array conversion issue?

Comment: define constants and then use`const data = form.sampleObservations.filter(filterByPhLevel);` in form use like this `data[0] || ''`

Comment: nope not working @Sundar

Comment: then the filter not matches see any error you getting it on console ` try with constatnts`